# Entity Framework Code First - Inheritance - Related Items Collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-class

I am trying to implement a model in EF6 using inheritance

I have a the following classes: 
Base
Comments
 
Page : Base
BlogPost : Base

Where both Page and BlogPost use comments in the same manner. So I define Base as

```
public class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And the comments class defined like so:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RelatedItemID { get; set; } // points to Base::ID
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I want to set up the database as "Table per Type", so there are individual tables for Page and BlogPost each with auto-increment int PK.

**Now the EF know which table Comment.RelatedItemID points to? i.e. Page or BlogPost**

What is the best way to implements this **without having to resort to "Table Per Hierarchy"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to set up the database as "Table per Type", so there are
>   individual tables for Page and BlogPost each with auto-increment int
>   PK

Here's a problem.
The description *looks like* [TPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.6), but since you want to use auto-increment primary keys for each descendant, it won't fit TPC, because ultimately you'll get duplicating primary keys in one entity set. Obviously, it isn't [TPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.5) too, because TPT assumes, that there is a "base" table with auto-increment IDs, while "derived" tables have non-auto-increment primary keys, that at the same time are foreign keys to "base" table.

It seems to me, that logically these entities are not related. I mean, that there are no cases, when you will want to query pages and blog posts, using single query. Hence, it is better to avoid inheritance in EF model.

I suggest you to re-design model this way:

```
// "abstract" tells EF, that this type doesn't require mapping
public abstract class CommentBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RelatedItemID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class PageComment: CommentBase {}
public class BlogPostComment :  CommentBase {}

public abstract Base<TComment>
    where TComment : Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
    public ICollection<TComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Page : Base<PageComment> { /* other page properties */ }
public class BlogPost : Base<BlogPostComment> { /* other blog post properties */ }
```

There is still inheritance in code, but there will be two different entity sets in EF model. OTOH, you'll get two separate tables with comments - one for pages, one for blog posts.

Comment: Thanks! This is a beautiful solution. I like it even more because Comments can become the biggest table by far and this way it's split it up nicely.